# is UPX able to pack Dylibs?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dylib

is UPX able to pack Dylibs ? it works very well with Mac Os X application executables, but I cannot make it pack a dylib it throws an UnknownExecutableFormatException exception. Nevertheless I can see a lot of references to dylibs in the mach-o part of upx source code. Any hints ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was possible on older versions of `UPX` if the dylib included an `init` or load command (eg. `LC_ROUTINES`). The developers withdrew this one version later though due to other unforeseen issues with trying to pack dylibs. So to answer your question, yes it is possible, but only under certain cirumstances, and ***not*** recommended.

```
Changes in 3.05 (27 Apr 2010):
  ...
  * Withdraw support for shared libraries on Darwin (Apple Mac OS X)
    because upx does not understand enough about .dylib.
  ..

Changes in 3.04 (27 Sep 2009):
  ...
  * new formats Dylib/i386 and Dylib/ppc32 support shared libraries
    [such as browser plugins] on Darwin (Apple Macintosh).  An existing
    -init function (LC_ROUTINES command) is required.
  ...
```